# Scala java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to link a PostgreSQL database to a scala/spark project.

I wrote **build.sbt**

```
name := "Hermes"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.1"
)
```

And i have method of connection :

```
def getDatasetFromSql(query: String): Dataset[Row] = {
val options = Map(
  "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "url" -> createConnection,
  "dbtable" -> query
)
val fromSqlDs: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(options).load
fromSqlDs.cache.printSchema()
fromSqlDs
}
```

There are no exceptions throw when I tape **sbt package**, but when I spark-submit my code, I have this exception thrown **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver**

I have already checked some answers here, about the use of *classOf[org.postgresql.driver]* and *SparkConf().setJars()*. No success at this point.

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue once. So at the first try I have downloaded the postgres driver and saved it in a particular path. Then run the spark application like as follows :

```
sbt package 
spark-submit --driver-class-path ~/jarDir/p‌​ostgresql-9.3-1102-j‌​dbc41.jar target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

As I was working with Ambari. So added the postgres driver directly to a custom parameter. So, next time no need to pass the postgres driver while running the command. Hope it helps.